# Jenkins: Dynamic List Subversion Tags

Tags: svn, dynamic, jenkins, parameters, tags

I have a Jenkins task for deploy SVN tags.
I have a List Subversion Tag parameter (TAGS) with my SVN repository to select the tag to deploy with a url like this  http://svnserver/tags/productA
I need add a previous parameter to select the product
Parameter: PRODUCTS
Values: productA, productB,....

and use the value selected in List Suversion tag parameter.
If PRODUCTS=productA then TAGS= http://svnserver/tags/productA
If PRODUCTS=productB then TAGS= http://svnserver/tags/productB

I tried with several plugin like "uno choice" or "active choices",.. but nothing.

Any idea.
Thanks

Comment: In case you would still like to give it a try with the active choices (née uno choice), feel free to open an issue in issues.jenkins-ci.org, component=active-choices-plugin. We will try our best to respond with a solution, or release a new version with the fix for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my company, we are using Git and Linux.

For some jobs, I need to display the Git branches and I've used the [Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) plugin (with a Groovy script).

Here is my configuration:
[image]

I think you can use the same template with a svn command like that:

```
svn ls -v ^/tags
```

Comment: Can you please post solution for this? I have a similar problem and want to know if there is any plugin to customize Subversion tags parameter? I want user to display subversion tags based on value selected in previous parameter

Comment: My company is now using Git and we stopped our SVN instance. So I'm not able to test this anymore :(